# How to anonymize credentials in database with CakePHP

Tags: php, security, cakephp, encryption

I have a little problem with my login credentials in my database. 
I'm working on a sensitive project where all datas need to be anonymized. 
This is my problem :

I'm using an email address and password to identify my users. But an email address is not a anonymous data, for example : `firstname.lastname@domain.com` . So I need to anonymize this data.

For my other data like `lastname` or `firstname`, I'm using `Security::encrypt($firstname,$privatekey)` in CakePHP. (My private key is unique for each users)

But my email address is use for users login and if I encrypt it by the same way, login doesn't work anymore. I tried to encrypt the email sent by my login form but the result is not the same than the first encryption.

I can't use a SHA method to encrypt this data because I need to display it in user's interface.

The only solution I would currently find would be to encrypt this data in my own way however it is not secure

My questions are :

- It is possible to encrypt this data and keep login working.
- If yes, how can I do this ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: 2-way encryption? [openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)  & [openssl_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php)

Comment: Just FYI, encrypting the email address won't anonymise the data because encryption is reversible.  If you need to anonymise the data in such a way that it's impossible to recover it then you need to use a strong cryptographic one way hash (at least SHA-256), preferentially with a salt.  This will make the data more or less irrecoverable (provided the salt remains secure, even if it doesn't it will still take a dictionary attack to recover any meaningful data)

Comment: @GordonM If I use SHA256 to hash my email address I can't display it. We are using our encryption method with a private key unique for each user and a salt so it's more complicated to reverse it

Comment: @ThomasRollet Then you've got 2 conflicting concerns.  If the data is anonymised then it cannot be displayed because that's the whole point of anonymising it.  If it can be displayed then it cannot be anonymised because it can be used to identify a specific user by a plaintext piece of data (which may even contain their name).  Are you confusing anonymity with security?

Comment: I'm not sure my idea is workable or not. But, if I was you, i will do this way. I may used 2 columns for email address with separate purpose. One column store hash version and another one column is asymmetrically-encrypted version that I can decrypt with an offline private key or something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion one - use randomized usernames so you can encrypt the email as well

Since you are already encrypting the first name you can also encrypt the email in the same way.

So then, how will the user log in?

The solution is to generate random usernames that each user can use. This way you cannot infer much from say "user19281a18a7as" since all other fields would be encrypted.

You need to be careful that the username is as random as possible, so don't use a sequence to generate it :)

Funnily enough your login screen will look more like asking for two passwords, since the username has turned into something that looks like a password as well...

#### Suggestion two

Use an API KEY to allow your users in. So instead of having an ugly username and a password, just have ONE ugly long API KEY that the user has to past into the login box.

It's not elegant, but if they want to be anonymous that's the price to pay :)

You can even use private/public keys if you want, since your users are familiar with them